# Where can I find bourbon and rum?

Tags: fallout-4

I've been playing the Nuka World DLC and one of the achievements is to make 20 different flavors of Nuka Cola at the crafting stations. One of the recipes called Nuka Bombdrop requires vodka, rum, bourbon, and Nuka Dark. I've got the Nuka Dark and vodka, but I've been exploring for some time now both in Nuka World and the Commonwealth and haven't come across any bourbon or rum!

Does anyone know of a location where these ingredients are? I've checked some stores as well and haven't seen it for sale.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I was looking for alcoholic beverages, the first place I would check is the bar, meaning the [Dugout Inn](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Dugout_Inn) or the [Third Rail](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/The_Third_Rail).

However, the exact contents of their stock is random. Since you're looking for Rum and Bourbon specifically, and for a specific use for which you only need one or two, I checked the wiki pages for permanent locations, and found this:

[Bourbon](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Bourbon)

> - Whitechapel Charlie always has some for sale.
> - Cabot House will have stored bourdon bottles in cabinets.

[Rum](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Rum)

> - In the basement refrigerator of the Cabot House.
> - On the Prydwen, in the briefing room.
> - In the basement of the D.B. Technical High School.
> - Off the cliff south of Fort Strong, floating in a cardboard box with a teddy bear.
> - At an unmarked, demolished swamp town south of Gunners plaza, floating in a cardboard box with a 2 teddy bears. Box is inside the ruins of a house with a red dog house next to it and just east of a house with green siding with the rear wall missing. Warning: 2 or 3 Yao Gaui's may be present at this green-sided house.
> - Inside Joe's Spuckies near Postal Square.
> - Behind a book shelf in the Croup Manor basement.
> - On a boat just north of Pickman Gallery, in a cardboard box with a teddy bear.